# Can AWS X-ray configured with jdk7?

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-xray

I am exploring the AWS X-ray for monitoring my application with java 7.But in documentation, I found that, It requires java 8 or later(https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-java.html).

Java 8 is required to up the xray or applicaton is needed to build in java 8?

If there is some process by which xray can be used with java 7?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to support Java 7. The SDK is developed on Java 8 which uses some features not available on older versions. You can download source from https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-java, modify it so it builds on Java 7 and use the built artifacts as needed.